# Google YouTube v3 API throwing 403 errors from new server

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have a basic implementation of the Google YouTube v3 API, using the [https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started#authentication-and-authorization][PHP library] and Simple Authentication. This was working before changing to a new server. Now, I can only seem to get 403 errors stating that the quota has been exceeded, or the project has been marked for deletion. Neither is true, from what I can tell.

I have tried the following:

- Disabling and re-enabling the YouTube API services.
- Removing all IPs from "Accept requests from these server IP addresses" area on the key configuration page.
- Created new keys with and without IP restrictions.
- Checked via whatismyip.com to ensure the server is making requests with the configured IP.

This is essentially my code:

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey('...');

    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $videosResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet, recordingDetails', array('id' => $videoId));
```

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Google API has a delay to update the new config values.Give it some time and try later may solve your problem.

Comment: I gave it 5 minutes before testing, and by now it's been weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be that there was some kind of mixup with the project existing in two accounts, instead of being shared. I supposed this was some kind of fallout from a Google upgrade. I disabled the API and deleted the project under one account, then regenerated the keys in the other, and haven't had the problem since.